# Convert ISO 8601 format to Hours in Excel

Tags: excel, powerbi, iso

I have an excel sheet with the ISO format of PT4H19M59S for duration column. I need to convert this value to number of hours in an easy way. Can someone help me with this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved. You just have to detect the data type(under transform tab) using power query and then can convert that to the duration in total hours